# backslashbox is too wide

Tags: tables

I feel the first column in my longtable is too wide. Please see the figure below
[image]

My code is:

```
\begin{center}  
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}  
\caption{Error rates for SVM and 100 random counts. \label{tab:2}}\\  
\hline  
\backslashbox{Concepts}{Train sizes} & 10 & 100 & 1000 & 10000 & 100000\\  
\hline  
1 & 0.49 (0.00) & 0.49 (0.00) & 0.47 (0.00) & 0.43 (0.00) & 0.33 (0.00)\\  
\hline  
\end{longtable}  
\end{center}
```

I wonder if there is some way to reduce the width of the first column?

Thanks and regards!

---

EDIT:

As Hugo suggested, I tried to specify the width for the first column.

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{50pt}|c|c|c|c|c|}
```

But it appears messed up

[image]

Comment: I don't find the width of the first column too bad.  If you start trying to narrow it, the text is going to be pushed close to the diagonal line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
\backslashbox{Concepts\kern-1em}{\kern-1em Train sizes}
```

or

```
\backslashbox{Concepts\kern-2em}{\kern-2em Train sizes}
```

or

```
\backslashbox{Concepts\kern-3em}{\kern-3em Train sizes}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to set the size of the first column like this:

```
\begin{longtable}{|p{50pt}|c|c|c|c|c|}
```

Have never worked with this *\backslashbox*. But this is the way you normally resize the columns in a longtable. Maybe it works..

EDIT:
Or another try:

```
\backslashbox[2cm]..
```

Comment: Thanks, Hugo! As you suggested, I tried to specify the width for the first column. But it appears messed up.